# Autodesk Forge Viewer : Snapper won't snap on selected objects

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a strange issue with forge snapper.

If some objects are selected (hilited in light blue), then the Snapper seems to ignore them completly.

That is, hovering the mouse on them does not give any visual effect.

Clicking on them, Snapper will give "-1" for nodeID.

[image]

Unselecting those objects make the snapper working again on the same objects.

The snapper is initialized like so :

```
this._snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper(this.viewer, {
    renderSnappedGeometry: true,
    renderSnappedTopology: false,
    markupMode: false,
    toolName: SnapperName, // Setting a custom name for "our" snapper, to avoid being mixed up with viewer created snapper before or after it with the same name 
});
```

Anyone could give some help ?

Thanks

---

Edit : I have @types/forge-viewer 7.69.1

Here is the callstack :

[image]

Comment: can you please confirm the Viewer version?

Comment: and can you pleaes add the callstack? we need to understand where this callback is coming from... thank you!

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves if you mean the version of @types/forge-viewer, it's 7.69.1

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves I added aditional information in the main thread. Thank you !